# Spring JPA repository methods stopped working

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-data-jpa

Following are the classes and repository

**Problem:** First three methods of my repository are not working, first two were working fine initially but once i got error in saving my object due to missing `AUTO INCREMENT` in my database table,so i added that but than these methods stopped working.

> Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'cststudent0_.id' in 'field list'

I have tried the solution of others having same exception but nothing work also i want to understand the reason what is actually going on. I am using spring JPA with MySQL.

UPDATED: I have tried few more common methods like `findOne()` and `findAll()` they are also not working, i think the returned type with `CSTStudent` (i.e. my entity) is causing this exception.

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "course_section_teacher")
    public class CourseSectionTeacher implements java.io.Serializable {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Long id;

        @OneToOne
        private Course course;

        @OneToOne
        private Section section;

        @OneToOne
        private Teacher teacher;
    //getter setter
    }


    @Entity
    @Table(name = "cst_student")
    public class CSTStudent implements java.io.Serializable {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Long id;

        @OneToOne
        private CourseSectionTeacher courseSectionTeacher;

        @OneToOne
        private Student student;

        //getter setter
        }


    public interface CSTStudentRepository extends CrudRepository<CSTStudent, Long> {


        List<CSTStudent> findByStudent(Student student);
        List<CSTStudent> findByStudentId(long studentId);



        @Query("Select csts FROM CSTStudent csts inner join csts.student s inner join csts.courseSectionTeacher cst "
                + "where s.id = :studentid and cst.id = :cstid")
        CSTStudent findUsingStudentAndCourseSectionTeacher(@Param(value="studentid") long studentid,@Param(value="cstid") long cstid);


@Query("Select csts.courseSectionTeacher FROM CSTStudent csts inner join csts.student s where s.id = :studentid")
        List<CourseSectionTeacher> findStudentCourses(@Param(value="studentid") long studentid);
    }
```

Comment: When you say the methods are not working what do you mean? the same exception?

Comment: yes the same exception

Comment: Your cst_student table doesn't have a column named `id`.